# How to structure a key value pair for soap request

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I need help (being new to SOAP in general) to create the following output in my request XML:

```
<values> 
<table> 
<key xsi:type="xsd:string">SOME_KEY</key> 
<value xsi:type="xsd:string">SOME_VALUE</value> 
</table> 
</values>
```

I just need to know how to structure this in PHP and the pass it to soapclient as a parameter for a method.

Comment: I suggest you pass it as a JSON string, not as XML. See JSON.org. The JSON representation could be something like: `{"results": {"key1": value1, "key2": value2} }`. PHP handles this very well. If you structure the name/value pairs as properties/values of an object, then do `json_encode()` it will automatically create the JSON string for you to use as the response.

Comment: That is handy advice, appreciated. To elaborate further the above XML construct is what the Service expects however when I create a key value pair it is sending it as the following: <item><key>SOME_KEY</key><value>SOME_VALUE</value></item> I need it to create the XML above.

Comment: I understand. Since you're programming the SOAP server, I was basically suggesting abandoning SOAP and going toward the newer RESTful model.

Answer (score 0):

```
        <pre1:results>
           <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
           <sys:KeyValuePairOfstringstring>
              <sys:key>str1</sys:key>
              <sys:value>str2</sys:value>
           </sys:KeyValuePairOfstringstring>
        </pre1:results>
```

In this case "results" is the IEnumerable< string, string > parameter name